# Output particular sections of txt file to csv?

Tags: perl, parsing, csv, sed

Say I have a txt file like below (it's obviously not 'text text text', I'm just showing that it's blocks of irrelevant text)

```
text text text
text text text 
text text text 
important section age=30
name=mike
text text text 
text text text 
text text text
```

I want to parse it and output only the 'important section' to csv so that my csv would look like below, i.e. age in one column and name in another

```
age    name
30     mike
```

How should I go about this? Perl? Sed? I'm not that familiar with either but hoping there is a straightforward enough solution.

Choroba actually answered the above perfectly for me but I fear I oversimplified my actual text file too much, it is more like below

```
Something:
 this
Something else:
 that
Something else:
 etc.
Sales 
2011 Sales:
 €3,000

()
2010 Sales:
 €2,000

()
2011 Growth Rate:
 50.00%

Contact Details
```

And the output I would ideally like is

```
2011 Sales    2010 Sales    2011 Growth Rate
3,000         2,000         50.00%
```

This, unfortunately, greatly complicates things. The output doesn't have to be exactly like above but as close as possible

Comment: So, how do you tell what is a meaningful line - is it because it starts with a year? Or because it has a colon at the end? Are all lines with euro symbols in them meaningful? Do they always only have one space in front of them? Before you write anything, you at least need to have rules so you and the code know exactly what you're interested in

Comment: The edited example is essentially a mirror of the file(s) I want to parse so I know I need to focus on all text between "Sales" and "Contact Details". I then need to create columns for "2011 Sales" (and include 3,000 in the row below it), create a column for "2010 Sales" (include 2,000 in a row below) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl solution. It keeps a flag telling whether we are in the important section. Everything important is remembered in an array and printed at the end:

```
perl -nE '$i = 1 if s/important section //;
          push @t, [$1, $2] if $i and /(.*)=(.*)/;
          }{
          for my $i (0, 1) {
              say join "\t", map $_->[$i], @t
          }' file.txt
```

Comment: Quick answer, thanks choroba! That works perfect for the example I gave here but my actual txt file is much more complicated. Any idea how I could alter this to work for the actual txt file I have?

Comment: @choroba +1, clean and idiomatic. Does `-E` enable `say` there?

Comment: @robocode Not unless you are more precise about the format of your file...please update your question with an example that is more representative of your actual input.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: Yes, `-E` enables `say` on Perls that support it.